# c# combobox selectedindex display

Tags: c#, combobox, display

I have a two combobox's on the same tab of a tab control. One combobox has as a SelectedIndexChanged event and in that event, the code tries to change the index of the second combobox. 
The code uses:

```
int index = comboB_DS_Term_Type.FindString("Test1");
comboB_DS_Term_Type.SelectedIndex = index;
```

But nothing is displayed in the combobox

If I use:

```
comboB_DS_Term_Type.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

The correct item is displayed in the combobox
I can set a breakpoint and check the value of the index is valid 
but nothing is displayed in the combobox
I have tried to refresh the combobox but still, nothing is displayed

Comment: Is there really an item in comboB_DS_Term_Type that has name Test1?

Comment: @Peter Simpson - Can you post the full changed event and the code that populates your combo boxes. Thanks

Comment: So you are saying that `comboB_DS_Term_Type.SelectedIndex = 2;` works, but `comboB_DS_Term_Type.SelectedIndex = index;` when you have set a breakpoint and verified that `index` is indeed `2` is not doing the same thing?

Comment: First of all, print out what your `index` is with `int index = comboB_DS_Term_Type.FindString("Test1");` `Console.WriteLine(index);` and see if it prints out 2. Otherwise, FindString doesn't do what you want it to, and you have to use another method to get your index.